# Use multiple transistors in order to control multiple buttons on a remote

Tags: transistors, relay

It is my first time using a transistor. I saw tutorials on the internet and thanks to those tutorials I manage it to work. But the tutorials only illustrate this using one button. I got one button working but when I try multiple it does not work.

My goal is that when I send a small voltage to the transistor for it to connect two cables simulating the press of a button.

I already managed to do this with a relay but my goal is to do this without a relay. I already got this working but it only works when I wire each button individually. The moment I wire all the buttons together it does not work. Can someone hemp me figure out what I am doing wrong?

The remote only has 4 buttons of interest that I am trying to remote control:

[image]

### **So this is partially working. For example I am able to simulate a button press like this:**

[image]

From the picture all the transistors are facing in the same direction having the left leg as the collector, middle leg as the base and right as emitter. I am able to simulate a button press if I do each button individual. The moment I connect the 4 emitters to the same end of the negative battery the remote control does not work! I guess the remote control is having a problem when all the buttons are connected together even though only one side is connected. How can I solve this problem? Having 4 raspberry pi would be a solution but it makes no sense. Before I was using relays it will be very cool if I can use a transistor.

Comment: Mostly a remote control doesn't support key combinations. So when you press, for example, two buttons nothing will happen. Better go for vectrols (google it) because it is more safe or use relais. Both methods are completely isolated and cannot damage the device because it just simulating a keypress by connecting just two points.

Comment: I just want to press one button at a time. But when I connect all emitters to ground this creates a problem. I guess I will have to go back to my old solution where I used relays :/

Comment: Please edit your question and add a schematic diagram that shows your circuit.

Comment: are you certain that the transistors are oriented correctly?

Comment: Regardless if the transistors are oriented correctly or not in order to close the switch I need to send a positive voltage to the  base and connect the emitter to ground. That works great. When I connect all the emitters to the ground the remote control stops working regardless if I add current to it or not. The reason is because all emitters are connected to the negative side of the button. For some reason connecting all the buttons together creates a conflict.

Comment: Use low Vgsth MOSFETS. Connect FET ds across buttons. For N Channel FETS, when gate is at ground FET is off. When gate is at supply FET is (probably) on. It somewhat depends on cct and voltages on switched points. It may be that P channel FETS work better with grounded gate = on and high gate = off. This does NOT have the problems that bipolar does.